# Redirection on codeigniter route

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have set this route on codeigniter:

```
$route['usuario/dar-baja']['POST'] = 'Private/Clients/dropClient';
```

But when I try to make a request this way:

```
$('#confirmed-drop').click(function(){
    var reason=$("#motivos_baja option:selected").val();
    $.post("{{ base_url }}usuario/dar-baja",{reason:reason});
});
```

The request return 302 redirect and a new GET request to the same URL occurs and because the route to handle GET request doesn't exist therefore I get a 404 page not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it is from CSRF, which is used by Codeigniter to ensure that users are unable to resubmit forms.

Disable CSRF on this link using these steps in `config.php`

```
$csrf_ignore = [

    'usuario/dar-baja'
];

$is_csrf_condition_met = true;

foreach($csrf_ignore as $ci){

    if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $ci) !== FALSE) {

        $is_csrf_condition_met = false;
        break;
    }
}

$config['csrf_protection'] = $is_csrf_condition_met;
```